# ios/objective-c: Create Segue from Textview to View Controller in Storyboard

Tags: ios, storyboard, segue

I would like a user to be able to tap on a textview (that does not accept input) and segue to another View Controller for editing the textview.

Is this possible using storyboard?

If you simply drag from the textview to the other view controller, you are not given an option to create a segue.

Thanks for any suggestions on how to do this.

Comment: Segues are between `UIViewController`. Do it from the `UIViewController` which contains your `UITextView`. You could detect when the `UITextView` is tapped and then perform the segue.

Comment: I was able to do a segue from a button to another VC...

Comment: That's because it trigger it's "parent view controller" to do the segue since segue are often done by user interaction, like pushing a button. That's just a convenient doing. But the main interest of a `UITextView` is to enter text.

Answer (score 1):

Connect your UITextView delegate to the view controller

[image]

Control-click and drag from the view controller icon to destination view controller to create a segue

[image]

Choose "show"

[image]

Click on the segue arrow and give it an identifier

[image]

Add the UITextViewDelegate to your view controller

`@interface ViewController <UITextViewDelegate>`

Implement the delegate method

```
- (BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"PUSH_NEXTVIEWCONTROLLER" sender:textView];
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: Does user interaction have to be enabled?  I had previously disabled it so that user would not think they could edit the actual textview on this screen or accidentally change it around but rather edit it on separate edit screen

Comment: If `userInteractionEnabled` is disabled, that view will not respond to any touch events, so it must be enabled. The only time you would ever want to disable it is if you wanted it to ignore all touches.